# json.net error: unexpected token deserializing object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a file with some json in it, that was generated by json.net:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Dashboard.Gauges.LabelGaugeSeed, Dashboard",
    "Text": "blah",
    "LabelColor": {
      "X": 1.0,
      "Y": 1.0,
      "Z": 1.0,
      "W": 1.0
    },
    "Center": {
      "X": 0.0,
      "Y": 0.0
    },
    "CharacterWidth": 0.05,
    "CharacterHeight": 0.1,
    "LineThickness": 0.01,
    "TextCentering": 0.5
  }
]
```

Which is giving me the aforementioned error while deserializing. Can anyone find a problem with this json? I ran it through a verifier and it said it was fine.

It errors on the space after "Center": If I change the order of the Center and the LabelColor properties, it then errors in the same manner after "LabelColor":

Here is a dump of the types:

LabelColor is an OpenTK Vector4, Center is an OpenTK Vector2, and LabelGaugeSeed is below:

```
public class LabelGaugeSeed : IGaugeSeed
{
    public IGauge Grow()
    {
        return new LabelGauge(this);
    }

    public string Text;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector4Converter))]
    public Vector4 LabelColor;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector2Converter))]
    public Vector2 Center;
    public float CharacterWidth;
    public float CharacterHeight;
    public float LineThickness;
    public float TextCentering;
}
```

And here is Vector4Converter:

```
public class Vector4Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Vector2);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.Read();
        var x = serializer.Deserialize<float>(reader);

        reader.Read();
        reader.Read();
        var y = serializer.Deserialize<float>(reader);

        reader.Read();
        reader.Read();
        var z = serializer.Deserialize<float>(reader);

        reader.Read();
        reader.Read();
        var w = serializer.Deserialize<float>(reader);

        return new Vector4(x, y, z, w);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Vector4 vectorValue = (Vector4)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("X");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.X);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Y");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.Y);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Z");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.X);

        writer.WritePropertyName("W");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.Y);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Vector2Converter is exactly the same, except for it doesn't contain code for the Z and W properties, and the name is different.

The deserialization process will go through the first one successfully, but not even get into the second one.

The Vector classes can be found here: https://github.com/opentk/opentk/tree/develop/Source/OpenTK/Math

Comment: Can you also post the C# types?

Comment: Could it be the $ sign in the "$type" property that is throwing it off?

Comment: Sanity check, but are you using the latest version of JSON.NET?

Comment: @HaukurHaf That is generated by json.net when you have the TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects set in the serialization settings.

Comment: @NateBarbettini it is the latest one from NuGet

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I have posted them.

Comment: Can you also post Vector2 & Vector2 types & their converters?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I've posted the converter for vector4, vector2 is basically the same, without the z and w properties. The Vector classes can be found here: https://github.com/opentk/opentk/tree/develop/Source/OpenTK/Math

Comment: you should see what character is failing - the exception should tell you that.

Comment: @DanielA.White The error message is as follows:

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '[0].Center', line 11, position 14.

Which is the space after "Center":

Comment: Why do you even need a converter?  X, Y, Z and W are public, *writable* fields so they serialize correctly out of the box.

Comment: @dbc because the vector* structs in opentk have quite a few fields that are not just x, y, z and w and they result in recursive references (for instance public Vector2 PerpendicularRight). Plus just having x, y, z and w makes the json way more readable.

Comment: Btw, you have a typo in the `Vector4Converter` code you posted above -- the `CanConvert` function should check `typeof(Vector4)`, not `Vector2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do the read is to load into a `JToken` and access the properties by name, like so:

```
public class Vector4Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Vector4);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var vec = new Vector4();

        if (token["X"] != null)
            vec.X = (float)token["X"];
        if (token["Y"] != null)
            vec.Y = (float)token["Y"];
        if (token["Z"] != null)
            vec.Z = (float)token["Z"];
        if (token["W"] != null)
            vec.W = (float)token["W"];
        return vec;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Vector4 vectorValue = (Vector4)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("X");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.X);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Y");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.Y);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Z");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.Z);

        writer.WritePropertyName("W");
        writer.WriteValue(vectorValue.W);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Loading into a `JToken` and accessing by name also allows the sender to write the JSON properties in any order, which is preferred since the [JSON spec states that property name/value pairs are unordered](http://json.org/).

Also, notice I fixed a couple mistakes in `WriteJson` (the code wrote `X` and `Y` twice) and a mistake in `CanConvert`.

Answer (score 13):

**Tl;dr** - The problem was in your `Vector[X]Converters`. You read all the properties, but didn't actually navigate to the end of the object. You need an extra `reader.Read()` right before the last line where you return your concrete object.

**The deeper explanation:**

JSON.NET is picky about the state of the `JsonReader` when you are writing a custom converter. You need to traverse all the way to the end of the reader, regardless of whether you actually need the remaining data (in other words, you can't return early).

In this example, you read the value you wanted (W), and then immediately returned a new concrete object since you have all the data you need. However, the `JsonReader` is still examining the property node, so JSON.NET thinks that there's still data waiting to be deserialized. This is why you get

> Additional text found in json string after finishing deserializing object

You can see this yourself if you put a breakpoint inside your `JsonConverter` and watch the state of the `reader` object as you advance through the tokens. On the last one, the state is:

```
...
Path: "LabelColor.W"
TokenType: Float
Value: 1.0
....
```

If you leave the `JsonReader` in that state, you'll get an error. But, if you do one last `reader.Read()`, then the state is:

```
...
Path: "LabelColor"
TokenType: EndObject
Value: null
...
```

Now JSON.NET is happy!

Comment: Because of weirdness like this, I would recommend using a JToken-based reader, like dbc posted.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation to the problem. I have actually used dbc's answer, so I will mark that one as accepted. Plus it should encourage people to create these correctly. The JToken solution is much more elegant than what I had.

Comment: It is more elegant for sure. Hopefully my explanation may help someone else who is trying to figure out why JSON.NET is barfing. Cheers!

Comment: This answer has helped me identify an issue within my `JsonConverter`. My while loop stopping condition was `While(reader.Read())` which was not enough since I had other objects that I was not done deserializing. I had to change my while loop to check for `reader.TokenType`. In my case, I was checking for `JsonToken.EndArray`.